# CRM 2011 C# Confirmation Box

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Can I have a confirmation box in a synchronous (or asynchronous) plug-in.
I need some confirmation for an import:
3 new products will be created
2 new departments will be created
(Click OK to Proceed)

Currently there is a staging entity for periodic price list imports from excel;
the plug-in is registered 'On Create' of this entity and creates or updates products and price list items (and creates, but does not update, departments, accounts, and classifications)

The user does not want to have to perform multiple imports every time the supplier releases a new price list; is there a better way to handle the whole situation?

Comment: If you elaborate, maybe someone can suggest a different approach. I'm not entirely clear on the task at hand. Please explain.

Comment: The task at hand is to create products, price list items, price lists, accounts and some custom entity records from a single import.

Comment: It sounds like a border-line to a bigger set of operations (especially if it's conceivable that there can be additional steps in the future). In that case, I'd suggest the approach I added in my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can have a message box (or any other UI interaction in a plug in. Sometimes, a plugin will be invoked by a service or a workflow with no users logged in at all. What would happen to the output window in such case?

As far my understanding goes, if you wish to communicate with the user, you need to rely on JS. The nice coding of .NET is, in CRM, reserved for server operations.

In case the number of operations to perform is large (or likely to grow larger and larger, as in your case), I'd go with the following approach.

Since the process is supposed to be invoked upon user interaction, I'd go with JavaScript, and implement an appropriate *onSomeEvent* method that creates a single instance of an auxiliary entity *Hazaa* (or perhaps ProducLineSetter*, to be more explicit on what it does).

Then, I'd deploy a plugin that responds to *Create* message and does all the magic for me. That includes creating/configuring all the required entities (prices, products and what not).

I love C#, so to keep my answer moderate I feel that I also need to add that the second step could be also resolved by a number of calls in JavaScript too. In such case, for the love of god, place it in a separate JS file and add it as a web resource.   :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to have a plug-in registered on create of an entity and create that entity with JavaScript when the user clicks a confirmation dialog.

Comment: I'd do that too, if it's just a few operations. However, if the number of stuff to do grows larger (e.g. creating 12 instances with 9 required fields each etc.), I'd put that code into a plugin and execute it upon creation of a single instance of an *invoker*. Note that the same may be achieved by adding a JS web resource and keeping the code there. I just prefer C# and try to do stuff using it. :)